# passing arguments to ElapsedEventHandler C#

Tags: c#, timer

This program is designed to open two COM ports and send data from one to the other ever 1 second. The user inputs which port transmits and which port recieves. The problem I am having is with the ElapsedEventHandler() takes in the OnTimedEvent() function which has two default arguments. I want the OnTimedEvent() function to write something to the send port and read it in on the recieve port, then display it to the console. Obviously my code will not work the way I have it now because the ports and message are not in the scope of OnTimedEvent(). What can I do to make that function work the way I want? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Timers;

public class serial_test1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sender;
        string recver;
        string buff_out;
        string message;
        SerialPort send_port;
        SerialPort recv_port;

        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            sender = "UART";
            recver = "USB";
            message = args[0];
        }
        else if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            sender = args[0];
            message = args[1];
            if (sender == "USB")
            {
                recver = "UART";
            }
            else
            {
                recver = "USB";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sender = "UART";
            recver = "USB";
            message = "TEST MESSAGE";
        }


        int baud = 115200;
        int data_bits = 8;
        Parity parity = Parity.None;
        StopBits stop_bits = StopBits.One;

        buff_out = message;

        SerialPort UARTport = new SerialPort("COM1", baud, parity, data_bits, stop_bits);
        SerialPort USBport = new SerialPort("COM7", baud, parity, data_bits, stop_bits);

        UARTport.Open();
        USBport.Open();


        if (sender == "USB")
        {
            send_port = USBport;
            recv_port = UARTport;
        }
        if (sender == "UART")
        {
            send_port = UARTport;
            recv_port = USBport;
        }

        string header = "from " + sender + " port to " + recver + " port";
        Console.WriteLine(header);

        Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        // Set the Interval to 1 second.
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        UARTport.Close();
        USBport.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string buff_in;
        send_port.WriteLine(buff_out);
        buff_in = recv_port.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(buff_in);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best thing you can do is learn OOP, your code looks 20 years old. Wrap the port operations in a class, wrap the timer in a class that has two ports as properties and voila - you have the objects you need where you need them. Keyword is `objects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `System.Threading.Timer` instead, you can pass in a state object into the constructor that is passed in to the `TimerCallback`.

Comment: I concur. I discourage using `System.Timers.Timer` at all because it swallows exceptions. See my blog post, http://blog.mischel.com/2011/05/19/swallowing-exceptions-is-hiding-bugs/, for information.

Comment: +1 - Didn't realize Timers still swallowed exceptions. Strange that the MSDN article explicitly states .NET 2.0 and below does this and "This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework." whereas it should say .NET 4.0 and below IMHO (unless I'm missing a subtle difference).

Comment: @keyboardP: Odd. In the documentation for the `Elapsed` event, it doesn't mention a particular version. But in the documentation for the class itself, it does mention .NET 2.0 and below.

Comment: @JimMischel - That is quite strange, seems like it may be an oversight. Maybe they thought that it would be fixed after .NET 2.0 and haven't updated the main class page...

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these options:

#### 01 - Simply use an auxiliar object

```
static string _value;
static void MyElapsedMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_value);
}
```

#### 02 - Or use a closed class

```
class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
    public string Data;
}

private void StartTimer()
{
    var timer = new CustomTimer
    {
        Interval = 3000,
        Data = "Foo Bar"
    };

    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = ((CustomTimer)sender).Data;
}
```